# Cannot GET / message

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, iis, single-page-application, iis-express

I am using VS 2017 preview edition, and trying to open `ASP.NET core 2.0 web application, that uses Angular template`

when i open the site `(f5 or ctrl-f5)`, the web-browser getting opened with the message

**`Cannot GET /`**.

[image]

I don't know what causing that and how to fix that, tried to clean/rebuild/restart VS/restart the computer, what else can I do to solve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by giving the project other port (right click on the project name from the solution explorer > click "properties" and change the ports that i marked, for example from 44381 to 54381:

- i don't know why this solved it.. but it did.
  [image]